# Which type of analysis to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to predict my DV based on IV (predictor variable) scores.
I have a sample size of 62.
DV is categorical (addicted or not addicted).
8 IVs are all continuous (at a push I can lose 3 IVs)
I only have access to SPSS.
Could you help me decide, please, the most appropriate and correct statistical analysis to use given the above information?
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds from what youve said that logistic regression or SVM might be a good place to start. What youre trying to do is called classification if that helps you in your research for the right analysis.

Comment: You really don't have enough data to include 8 IVs.  You probably don't have enough data for 5. How many addicted's vs not's do you have?

Comment: 17 addicted and 45 not. If it helps, I also have continuous data for the DV.

Comment: Use the continuous data for the DV. With only 17 cases in the least-frequent category, one could argue that you don't even have enough cases for 2 IVs. A useful rule of thumb is that 10-20 cases in the least-frequent outcome category are needed per IV. Pre-binning data before analysis, as you seem to have done with your DV, is seldom a winning formula.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by pre-binning data but I can assure you that no useable data has been disgarded.

Answer (score 0):

- Use continuous data for DV as forcing it to categorical (2 categories -addicted or not addicted) leads to information loss
- For 8 (or even 5) predictors, sample size is very less (You may need more sophisticated techniques to handle such data)
- Either try to gather more data (recommended)
- Or try to use dimension reduction techniques (such as PCA) for variable selection (Literature review may also help/support)
- Try using both of the above mentioned options